# when I fetched a table from Mysql the data in a cell displayed in a continuous line, but i want them as a list. I have attached the code

Tags: mysql

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>International Holidays</title>
<style>
td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}
a {
    text-decoration:none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

tr:hover {
    background-color: #f5f5f5
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
//to display in MYSQL in an HTML table form//

<?php
//connect to MYSQL
$db = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "kashmir@123",     "internationalholidays")
or die('Error connecting to MySQL server.');
$query = "SELECT * FROM sheet1";
mysqli_query($db, $query) or die('Error querying database.');

$result = mysqli_query($db, $query);

if ($result->num_rows>0) {
    echo "<table><tr><th>country</th><th>cities</th></tr>"; 
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {  
    echo "<tr>  
        <td>".$row["country"]." </td>   
        <td>".$row["cities"]." </td>    
    </tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$db->close();
?>
```

Comment: Note: Do try to avoid posting your passwords on the internet.